Merging two version of code in Git giving Already up to date
I have two sets of code, one is cloned from some remote named as Development. Now there is some scenario for which I have updated code from the same codebase locally from some other developer which needs to be merged in the branch Development. I have created a new branch NewVersion from Development, deleted all the code in NewVersion and pasted the local code there and committed the code. Now I am merging Development into NewVersion hoping I'll get conflicts but it says Already up to date.
git merge Development
//Already up to date


If the new changes are on NewVersion, merging Development (older) into it is a no-op because there are no commits on Development missing on NewVersion. Merges are not symmetrical operations. What do you want to achieve here? Bring these new changes into Development? If so it's the other way around. Merge NewVersion into Development.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that there are lots of changes already done in Branch Development. These changes, I want in branch NewVersion

I tried to merge the NewVersion into Development and it just replaces the old code, so I discarded the merge.

Oh, okay then. So your local branch is probably not up-to-date. Either git pull from your Development branch or just git fetch then merge the <remote>/Development remote-tracking branch into NewVersion.

I strongly recommend you to run gitk --all (after having run git fetch first) to get a full overview of your history and the relations between your branches.

Here, I have created the new_version branch from the main branch, which already contains the latest version of the code.
images:

I created the new_version branch from the main branch.


Next, I made changes to the README.md file in the new_version branch, added and committed those changes, and then tried to merge the main branch into the new_version branch. However, since the new_version branch was created from the main branch, it showed "Already up to date."

Keep in mind that if you merge the new_version branch back into the main branch, the main branch will be updated with the changes made in the new_version branch, effectively replacing the code in the main branch with the updated code from the new_version branch.



